# how to set max limit for pagination in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

My code

```
  $this->paginate=array(
          'conditions' =>array('OrderDetail.order_id'=>$id),
            'maxLimit' => 500));
```

---

```
$this->paginate=array(
          'conditions' =>array('OrderDetail.order_id'=>$id),
            'limit' => 500));
```

Both result giving me 100 records max thou i set limit as 500,as if i set 500 i need 500 records.!  can any body help me on this ?

Comment: According to the documentation ( http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#limit-the-maximum-number-of-rows-that-can-be-fetched ), maxLimit and limit are both correct. But you need both in the same query to work as they do different things.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you think about it: You need to combine them.

```
public $paginate = array(
    // other keys here.
    'maxLimit' => 500,
    'limit' => 500
);
```

You need to first raise the maxLimit to the absolute limit you want to allow.
Then you can set the limit to any value up to this point.
Only setting one of them does not change anything (logically).

Comment: You need to be more specific - and update your question above with your complete example code.

Comment: Works great , may I know if this is all about CakePHP or it depends upon sql/mysql ?

Answer (score 0):

Set paginator limit to blank

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array('limit' => '');
```

Now paginator will find all records from table

Comment: This works, but throws: Warning (2): Division by zero [CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/PaginatorComponent.php, line 214]

Comment: @Naidim If you want to list all records you don't need to use Paginator at all as Paginator is only used to show selected number of records and others will be listed only if called with help of paging.

Comment: Duh! Thanks! Get so lost in the trees, forget to step back to see the forest.

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array('limit' => '-1');
```

Add this in start of your function and it will get all data without any error.